# How chrome identifies Reload and Leave buttons on the "beforeunload" event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

[Here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10468996?hl=en) I am attaching the description. I am curious to know how chrome is able to identify it.